# Copy tasks from one planner to another using power automate

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-planner

How to copy tasks from one planner to another using power automate based on trigger (when task is created in Planner 1)?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of information provided by the trigger isn't enough, then:

1. Use the '*Get a task*' action to retrieve the details of the task created with the trigger's ID.
2. Use the data from that in a '*Create a task*' action in the desired planner location.

Comment: I am able to clone task with ''Get a task'' from source planner to clone planner based on task creation trigger, however task is not getting created in correct bucket instead it is getting created automatically in 1st bucket. I have selected Bucket ID from dynamic fields for clone planner just like I selected title, title is getting copied correctly.  Also how to get checklist and notes as those field labels are not there in 'Create a Task' for clone planner. Flow attached in question for ref.

Comment: IRRC Bucket assignment is something that you have to do with a Graph API call. I had a full 'Project' setup (creation of SharePoint sites, Teams tabs, everything) at a previous job, but I got the bums rush, and couldn't take my templates outta there. It can be done, though, I think. But mainly base things on the above, and send yoursel a notification with a link to manuall move it to the right bucket until you have an API fix.

Comment: I have a similar flow and want to create a task for each assignee, even in the same bucket. The problem here is, that I can't set the creator of the task explicitly. Since I created the flow, I'm always the creator.
Is there a way to copy the task and use the original creator?